# Python text based game winning condition not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been using everyone's suggestions to help me to write this script, and I am greatly appreciative. My game works great until i get to the final room with all of my items.  I can't seem to get my winning conditions to work. I currently have them as an outer loop but I have tried them as the first inner loop and even a second inner loop. no matter where I put the winning conditions I cant seem to get them to work. I have also tried different things with the inventory to help make the winning conditions work I have been beating my head against the wall for days and I just cant seem to find the solution.

```
enter code here
```

def game():
answer = input('Would you like to help Galatrix save Halloween Town?(y/n)')

```
    if answer.lower() == 'y':
        print('Great! Welcome to Halloween Town!')
        instructions()

    else:
        print('Too bad they really need your help.')
        exit()


# define rules
def instructions():
    print('Galatrix and her mentor have been noticing some strange goings on in their home of Halloween Town.')
    print(
        'Help Galatrix find all 6 items she needs to finish the potion to charge the Ancient wand and defeat the Warlock.')
    print('Collect 6 items around Halloween Town. Then head to the theater to face off with the Warlock.')
    print('Move commands: North, South, East, West')
    print("Add objects to inventory: type 'get'.")
    print("To end the game at any time, just type 'end'.")
    print('*****************************')
    # define rooms

    # remind user what room they are in
rooms = {'Town Square': {'name': 'Town Square> Home of the Jack-o-lantern.', 'North': 'Dentist', 'South': 'General Store', 'East': 'Rec Center', 'West': 'Galatrix House', 'object': '0'},
        'Galatrix House': {'name': 'Galatrix House', 'East': 'Town Square', 'object': 'Cloak'},
        'Dentist': {'name': 'Dentist', 'South': 'Town Square', 'East': 'Hair Salon', 'object': 'Vampire tooth'},
        'Hair Salon': {'name': 'Hair Salon', "West": 'Dentist', 'object': 'Werewolf hair'},
        'General Store': {'name': "General Store", 'North': 'Town Square', 'East': 'Mentor House', 'object': 'Cauldron'},
        'Mentor House': {'name': 'Mentor House', 'West': 'General Store', 'object': 'Ancient Wand'},
        'Rec Center': {'name': 'Rec Center', 'North': 'Theater', 'West': 'Town Square', 'object': 'Ghost sweat'},
        'Theater': {'name': 'Thearter', 'South': 'Rec Center', 'object': 'Warlock'}
             }
current_room = rooms['Town Square']
end_point = rooms['Theater']


def move(player, direction):
    current_room = player
    if directions in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
    else:
        print('There is nothing in that direction.')
        return current_room


# define supplies
inventory = []
Inventory = {}
def add_to():
    if object not in Inventory:
        Inventory[object] = 1
    else:
        pass



# define directions
directions = {'North', 'South', 'East', 'West'}
game()
while True:
    if current_room['name'] == 'Warlock' and Inventory == 6:

        print('CONGRATULATIONS!!! YOU SAVED HALLOWEEN TOWN!!!!!')
        exit('The End')
    elif Inventory != 6 and current_room['name'] == 'Theater':
        print('Keep searching.')

    print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Inventory: {}'.format(inventory))
    command = input('\nWhat do you do?')
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
            print('You see the {}.'.format(current_room['object']))

        else:
            print("You can't go that way.")

    elif command == 'get':

        if current_room['object'] != '0':
            print('You grabbed the {}.'.format(current_room['object']))
            inventory.append(current_room['object'])
            current_room['object'] = '0'
            add_to()


        elif current_room['object'] == '0':
            print("I don't see anything here.")


    elif command in quit:
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break

    else:
        print('You can not go that way.')
```

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library

Comment: Share your Error code